# Magento 2 Bundle price

Tags: php, magento, magento2, price

I would like to ask you for some help or even just a comparison.

On my site I have bundles that are dimanically priced with select products, some with radio and some with default.

Magento 2 however shows two different prices between listing and product page. I have checked at code level and on the product page there is a manipulation via js that changes the price. In fact when the page loads you see a price before the update. Have you ever implemented some solution to make the same prices appear?  This is the piece of code I am trying to implement but without success as it returns the same price because the products are set to default even though they are not selected on the product page.

```
     $product = $this->productRepository->get($product_sku);
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
        $children_ids = $this->bundleType->getChildrenIds($product->getId(), true);
        $bundle_items = [];
        $optionsCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getOptionsCollection($product);
        foreach ($optionsCollection as $options) {
            $optionArray[$options->getOptionId()]['option_title'] = $options->getDefaultTitle();
            $optionArray[$options->getOptionId()]['option_type'] = $options->getType();
            if ($options->getType() !== 'checkbox' && $options->getRequired() === "1") {
                foreach ($selectionCollection as $selection) {
                    foreach ($children_ids as $bundle_id) {
                        if ((array_values($bundle_id)[0] === $selection->getEntityId())
                            && $options->getId() === $selection->getOptionId()) {
                            $price = $selection->getPrice();
                            $qty = $selection->getSelectionQty();
                            $bundle_items[] = $price * $qty;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        $finale_price = array_sum($bundle_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by creating a function that would return the tier price. Mine is a bit more customised because I have different prices depending also on the customer group. I'll leave the code.

```
public function getBundlePrice($product_sku, $product_sal)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($product_sku);
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
        $children_ids = $this->bundleType->getChildrenIds($product->getId(), true);
        $bundle_items = [];
        $optionsCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getOptionsCollection($product);
        foreach ($optionsCollection as $options) {
            $optionArray[$options->getOptionId()]['option_title'] = $options->getDefaultTitle();
            $optionArray[$options->getOptionId()]['option_type'] = $options->getType();
            if ($options->getType() !== 'checkbox' && $options->getRequired() === "1") {
                foreach ($selectionCollection as $selection) {
                    foreach ($children_ids as $bundle_id) {
                        if ((array_values($bundle_id)[0] === $selection->getEntityId())
                            && $options->getId() === $selection->getOptionId()) {
                            $price = $selection->getPrice();
                            $qty = $selection->getSelectionQty();
                            if ($qty > 1 || $selection->getTierPrice()) {
                                $price = $this->getCustomPrice($selection);
                            } else if ($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId() === "2") {
                                $price = $selection->getPartnerPrice();
                            }
                            $bundle_items[] = $price * $qty;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->calculator->getAmount(array_sum($bundle_items), $product_sal);
    }
```